# confused about versioning in google play console

Tags: android, version-control, google-play, publish

I have :

- an old app with version '1' published in Production a year ago on Google Play. Target SDK 22.
- a newer app with version '2' actually published to Production with a rollout rate of 20% (default). Target SDK 25

Question :
Is the old app still be visible and downloadable for any user/device, or is the app with version '1' deactivated in general ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target SDK does not affect app delivery, just min/max SDK, so that's a red herring.

The short answer: at the moment 20% of your users will get version 2, 80% version 1. When you finally increase rollout to 100%, version 1 will be automatically fully deactived.

The longer answer: In more complicated situations app targeting comes into play. This does not apply in the situation in your question. Suppose version 1 was minSdk 22 and version 2 was minSsk 25. Each user would be randomly put in a group "rollout" or "old" in the ration 20:80. If they are in the group "old" they will get version 1. If they are in the group "rollout" then their Sdk would be checked. If it was >25 they would get "rollout". Otherwise they would fallback and get "old". When rollout reaches 100%, users with SDK <25 would no longer be served anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to rollout 20% (20% of already installed version '1' are upgradeable to '2') and completely deactivate version '1' at the same time. I mean 100% means all installed apps. So 80% will still persist on version '1'. But what is with new users. Or in other words. "80% will get version '1'" does not make sense, because 80% from what ?

Comment: No, new users are always in the same ratio as existing users. Out of interest, why would you want them to be treated differently?

Comment: Ok. Not sure I understood. Means 4 new users get version 1, 1 new user get version 2 and so on, rigth?

Comment: Ok understood. Good explained. Thanks you.

Comment: The implementation is actually a random function based on the user id. It isn't done in a fixed "4 users v1, then 1 v2". Suppose user ids were randomly assigned between 1 and a billion. Then you could imagine users with user id >800,000,000 would get V2, and users with id < 800,000,000 would get v1 (so a given user always gets the same version). It doesn't work exactly like this, but it's a good way of understanding it.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks you very much.